# Nginx Reverse Proxy - Showing Real IP

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

I configured a nginx as reverse proxy. I wanna access to a site by two below addresses:

1. stats.test.com
2. test.com/stats

test.com and stats.test.com located on 2 diffrent servers. my problem is that when client access  the site by stats.test.com, every thing is OK and nginx shows client ip. but when client access site by test.com/stats nginx shows the Nginx reverse proxy server IP.
frontend configuration for stats.test.com:

```
upstream stats.test.com{
  server 192.168.0.130;
}

server {
  include /etc/nginx/default_server_settings;
  server_name  stats.test.com;

  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/default_location_settings;
    proxy_pass http://stats.test.com;
  }
}
```

frontend configuration for test.com/stats:

```
upstream test.com{
  server 192.168.0.11;
}

upstream stats{
  server 192.168.0.130;
}

server {
  listen 80 default;
  include /etc/nginx/default_server_settings;
  server_name test.com;

  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/default_location_settings;
    proxy_pass http://test.com;
  }

  location /stats/ {
    proxy_pass http://stats/;
  }
}
```

backend configuration for stats :

```
server {
   listen   80 default;

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/stats_access.log;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/stats_error.log;

   # Disable all methods besides HEAD, GET and POST.
   if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
     return 444;
   }

   root /var/www/stats/public_html;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   server_name stats stats.test.com;

   location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   location /doc/ {
     alias /usr/share/doc;
     autoindex on;
     allow 127.0.0.1;
     deny all;
   }

   location ~* \.(js)$ {
     expires 14d;
   }

   # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
   location ~\.php$ {
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi_params;
   }

   # Return a 404 for all text files.
   location ~* ^/(?:README|LICENSE[^.]*|LEGALNOTICE)(?:\.txt)*$ {
     return 404;
   }
}
```

I set this in nginx.conf:

```
set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.2;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For
```

`192.168.0.2` is nginx reverse proxy server ip.

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can use instead of $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and if you use nginx will appear the ip of the client, not reverse proxy.

Comment: i wanna use client ip to make a restriction based on IP range in NGinx

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but your stats.exemple.com site include the following:

```
include /etc/nginx/default_location_settings;
```

your URI based server is not, I bet that the include default_location_settings file include such proxy_header and proxy settings that do the trick like real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For